# Getting unique values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, seq

I have a sequence data and I importing it in the data frame. I want to have each distinct letters from the entire data frame and not from the each row.

The data frame looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

```
df<-data.frame(V1=c("m h j i d a","j h o f k l","g k o d m a"))
unique(unlist(apply(df,1,strsplit,split=" ")))
```

Comment: Or `split=""` if there are not spaces between the letters.  It is difficult to tell based on the question.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Just a quick question. You used 'apply' function and as far as I know apply is useful when the data in the data frame is of equal length. Do you know anyway to generalize this for even unequal data?

Comment: @Krish As far as I know "unequal data" is not a specific, well-defined thing in R. Maybe you should consider making a proper example with code (like the first line of this answer has).

Comment: @MatthewLundberg : Definitely. Depending on the pic, I did that. Maybe **Krish** can help us on this occasion by providing sample of data frame.

Comment: @Krish : I am unable to understand you. Will you please explain **Do you know anyway to generalize this for even unequal data?** by providing the reproducible data frame.

Comment: Yes sure, I am writing a function to get the unique values so my code in the function needs to be general. Suppose my data frame is as follows: 

df <- data.frame(V1=c("m h j k l", "e J h", "e r t g h j k l"))

will 'apply' work here too?

Comment: @Krish : Why not? Use the code. Btw, if you got your answer from my post please accept it.

Comment: Yes I used it for different types of data and it worked well. I apologise for not being an ideal Stack user as this is my first experience here. Thank you.